# Is it advisable to use ini files to configure a framework?

Tags: php, configuration, ini

I was wondering if it is advisable to use php .ini files to set up a framework. I have like 10 settings to store and since now I was doing that with constants. But I came across these .ini files. You can parse them and get all the variables you need.

Is is advisable to use .ini files to store framework configurations? How should I store them to make them global? Registry class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly OK and very common in fact. I might recommend that you store them in a configs folder. E.g. `/path/to/docroot/configs` (or "config" if you prefer)

You could easily parse them using `Zend_Config_Ini` http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html

You don't have to use the entire framework to use that utility. It's great and I would recommend it to anyone.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini('/configs/app.ini');
```

And yes storing it in a registry class is a great idea. The Zend Framework also has `Zend_Registry` if you wanted to use that, or just make your own.

Comment: Zend utility was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: +0 I'd argue that while it is common it is also superfluous. You can just as well use a plain old array and save time on the parsing process. Also, I dont see why I would want to use Zend_Config when I can just use parse_ini_file. Last but not least, a Registry is effectively a global with all the problems globals have unless you refrain from accessing it from everywhere in your code.

Comment: @Gordon I totally see where you're coming from in regards to the Registry; however, I feel like it's perfectly acceptable for something like config files. That's basically all I use it for personally. I've never run into the typical global issues you mentioned using it in that manner.